# Prove there is no smallest positive irrational number.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Proof: Assume by way of contradiction that there is a smallest positive irrational number $x$ where $x\in\mathbb{R-Q}$. Consider $0<x/2<x$, because $x$ is irrational $x/2$ is also irrational.

I am confused about how I would show $x/2$ is irrational. I know that a number is irrational if it is not rational but I don't know how to show $x/2$ is not rational. Any tips would be appreciated! I did have one idea that is shown below, it is a continuation of the above proof.

If $x/2$ was assumed to be rational, then there would have to exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $x/2=a/b$. Multiplying by two we get $x=2a/b$ where $2a$ and $b$ are integers thus making a rational which is a contradiction because $x$ was assumed to be irrational.

Comment: If $x/2$ is rational then so is $2(x/2)$, but that's not true, so yeah, your idea is fine.

Comment: You did completely fine with the proof by contradiction.